# Большая или маленькая буква после частицы?

Tags: орфография

У Розенталя есть правило, которое – оно в 12-м параграфе здесь, а именно в конце самом: http://rosental-book.ru/ortho_iii.html#sect11 – говорит, что если частица предложение прерывает, то продолжение предложения пишется с маленькой буквы, т. е. с неё начинается. В РАН-учебнике я ничего похожего вообще не нашёл, в связи с чем я интересуюсь, действительно ли до сих пор это правило Розенталя или оно уже недействительно.

Как правильно?

`1. Леополь, ах! Оставьте меня в покое!`

`2. Леополь, ах! оставьте меня в покое!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы записала так:

1. *Леополь, **ах!** Оставьте меня в покое!*
2. *Оставьте, **ах!** меня в покое, Леополь!*

**Пояснение**

1. Во всех приводимых примерах междометие **прерывает речь,** там нет **других знаков** (к примеру, запятой после обращения). Поэтому обращение можно разместить в конце предложения.
2. Это правило есть еще в "Правилах орфографии и пунктуации" **1956 года**, можно посмотреть на **[Грамоте.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/139-prop)**

§ 93. **С прописной** буквы пишется первое слово, следующее за знаком восклицательным, поставленным после обращения или междометия, находящегося в начале предложения, например: О Bолгa! После многих лет я вновь принес тебе привет (Некрасов). ***Ах!** Поскорее бы эта ночь прошла* (Чехов).

**Примечание.** Слово, следующее за восклицательным знаком, поставленным после междометия **в середине предложения**, пишется со строчной буквы например: *Я дo сих пор не могу позабыть двух старичков прошедшего века, которых, **увы!** теперь уже нет* (Гоголь).

3. **В других** учебных материалах оно тоже упоминается, например: [Знаки препинания при междометиях](https://%20%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85)  Марья, знаешь, шедровита, Да работать, **ух!** сердита! [Некрасов "Сват и жених"](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8_(%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82_%D0%B8_%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85)
4. В современных текстах такое оформление применяется не часто, все примеры приводятся из **классики**. Вероятно, поэтому правило не рассматривается в ПАС под ред. Лопатина. В то же время  его никто не отменял, и оформление можно использовать для **стилизации** текста (особая манерность, изысканность, ирония). Придает речи своеобразный шарм.

Comment: Вот здесь хороший ответ, можете, когда хотите, давно не было за что вам лайк поставить.

Comment: Спасибо! Я ведь стараюсь)

Comment: Но исправлять неправильные ответы совсем не стараетесь)

Comment: А что значит аббревиатура *ПАС*?

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр  Это Полный академический справочник.

Comment: Вроде бы сейчас междометия через вставку оформляют. Да?